# Installing Windows 8 after Ubuntu 13

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have install ubuntu and then resize ubuntu partition and install windows 8

Now I can't boot into windows and GRUB dont't find windows on /dev/sda4 partition

What do I need to do?

bootinfo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6137326/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Boot-Repair

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

(Tutorial is on the link)

Comment: boot-repair also don't help. it find two my kernels but don't see windows

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in order to add the necessary boot files to the bootloader partition ("EFI boot partition" in ubuntu or "System Reserved" in windows) alongside the ubuntu files: https://superuser.com/q/460762 (check the best answer).

You're going to need a windows 8 install disk or recovery disk for this.

After you do this procedure, you're going to need to run `boot-repair` in ubuntu. Only then, the utility will enable the windows boot files to be seen by GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing two efi partitions. So far systems really only work with one and your sda4 is not an efi partition anyway.

Use gparted on live installer and remove boot flag from sda4.

Then if it does not boot, updates will work as everything is confused by two efi partitions.